# How to center a section with bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using bulma framework ,  and all the content is to the left, how would I center the content on the page?  For example this image is to the left.

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <figure>
        <img src="/assets/images/norris-lake.jpg" alt="Melton Hill Lake">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [Bulma docs for Centering columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#centering-columns)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
      <div class="column is-half">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="Melton Hill Lake">
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I am still trying to go threw documents, I find myself lost at times , at where I need to look.  I tried the "is-centered"  but did not help  so the "is-half" with it is the key.  Thanks for help!

Comment: this solution solve the problem but make the page not responsive, the column is gonna be beside each other even in small screen

Answer (score 0):

I have the `<figure>` tag only inside the `<div class="columns is-centered is-mobile">`. And it works for me.